# Prevent CSS flicker on hover on first time render

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, flicker

When i render first time, while hovering on sidebar menu items. There's some flicker(like 0.2-0.5s white flash) happening on sidebar img and div.

Then after hovering over all items in sidebar post first render, that flicker doesn't appear in second time onwards.

I want to prevent this flicker in first time itself.

I tried overflow:hidden on parent container, backface-visibility:hidden, etc but still no luck.

Below is the relevant html and css code

**HTML**

```
        <div
          className={
            this.state.sidebarExpanded
              ? "expanded-sidebar bg-white"
              : "sidebar bg-white"
          }
          onMouseOver={this.expand}
          onMouseLeave={this.collapse}
        >
          <nav className="navbar mt-3 pr-0">
            <ul className="navbar-nav side-navbar">
              <span title="coming soon">
              <li
                className="nav-item disabled"
                onMouseOver={this.handleHover("dashboard")}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleHover("")}
               
              >
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link sidebar-nav-link py-3"
                  to="/commerce-studio/dashboard"
                 
                >
                  <span className="menu-items p-0">
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center h-30">
                      <p className="commDashboardImage mb-0"></p>
                      <p className="sidebar-full-name mt-1">Dashboard</p>
                      {/* <img src={wip} alt="wip" className="ml-2" /> */}
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              </span>
              <li
                className="nav-item"
                onMouseOver={this.handleHover("engageAI")}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleHover("")}
              >
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link sidebar-nav-link py-3"
                  to="/commerce-studio/offerHub"
                >
                  <span className="menu-items p-0">
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center h-30">
                      <p className="engageAIImage mb-0"></p>

                      <p className="sidebar-full-name mt-1">Offer Hub</p>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </NavLink>
              </li>

              <li
                className="nav-item"
                onMouseEnter={this.handleHover("oppo")}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleHover("")}
              >
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link sidebar-nav-link py-3"
                  to="/commerce-studio/merchantsHub"
                >
                  <span className="menu-items p-0">
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center opportunity-explorer-class h-30">
                      <p className="opportunityImage mb-0"></p>
                      <p className="sidebar-full-name mt-1">Merchants Hub</p>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </NavLink>
              </li>

              <li
                className="nav-item"
                onMouseOver={this.handleHover("campaignHub")}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleHover("")}
              >
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link sidebar-nav-link py-3"
                  to="/commerce-studio/suggestedMerchants"
                >
                  <span className="menu-items p-0">
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center opportunity-explorer-class h-30">
                      <p className="campaignHubImage mb-0"></p>
                      <p className="sidebar-full-name mt-1">
                        Suggested Merchants
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </NavLink>
              </li>

              <li
                className="nav-item"
                onMouseOver={this.handleHover("results")}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleHover("")}
              >
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link sidebar-nav-link py-3"
                  to="/commerce-studio/offerMap"
                >
                  <span className="menu-items p-0">
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center h-30">
                      <p className="resultsMapImage mb-0"></p>
                      <p className="sidebar-full-name mt-1">Offer Map</p>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </NavLink>
              </li>
```

**CSS**

```
.com_sidebar_div {
  .sidebar {
    width: 61px;
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid #ebeef1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.5s;
    // transition-property: border-right, border-width;
    // transition-delay: 0.3s;

    z-index: 0;
    .expanded-sidebar-img {
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 56px;
    }
    .nav-item {
      .sidebar-nav-link.active {
        .menu-items {
          div {
            border-right: 2px solid #419e7d;
            width: 60px;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.4s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
            transition: width 0.4s;
            height: 24px;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition-property: border-right, border-width;
            transition-delay: 0.5s;
          }
          .sidebar-full-name {
            white-space: nowrap;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .expanded-sidebar {
    width: 220px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 1000;
    // transition-property: border-right, border-width;
    // transition-delay: 0.3s;

    .nav-item {
      .sidebar-nav-link.active {
        .menu-items {
          div {
            -webkit-transition: width 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
            transition: width 0.5s;
            border-right: 2px solid #419e7d;
            transition-property: border-right, border-width;
            transition-delay: 0.9s;
            margin-right: 1px;
            width: 220px;
            height: 24px;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          .sidebar-full-name {
            color: #419e7d;
            white-space: nowrap;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .sidebar-full-name {
    color: #4a5c7b;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .minimize-text {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
  .min-button {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 17px;
  }

  .opportunity-explorer-class {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5rem 0rem !important;
  }

  .side-navbar {
    width: 205px !important;
    // padding-left: 2px !important;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-link.active:hover {
    .commDashboardImage {
      background: url(../../../engageStudio/assets/images/dashboard-icon.svg)
        no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;
      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .engageAIImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/offerHubHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .opportunityImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/merHubHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .campaignHubImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/sugMerHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .resultsMapImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/offersMapHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    // .expanded-sidebar-img {
    //   background: url(../../../engageStudio/assets/images/maximize-button.svg) no-repeat center;
    //   padding-right: 60px;
    //   height: 30px;
    // }
    .nav-item {
      .menu-items {
        div {
          p {
            .sidebar-full-name {
              color: #419e7d;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .nav-item:hover {
    .menu-items {
      div {
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
        transition: width 0.5s;
        border-right: 2px solid #419e7d;
        // margin-right: 1px;
        width: 220px;
        height: 24px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    }
    .sidebar-full-name {
      color: #419e7d;
    }
  }
  .sidebar-nav-link.active {
    .commDashboardImage {
      background: url(../../../engageStudio/assets/images/dashboard-hover.svg)
        no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .engageAIImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/offerHubHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .opportunityImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/merHubHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .campaignHubImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/sugMerHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .resultsMapImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/offersMapHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;

      padding-right: 58px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .nav-item {
      .menu-items {
        div {
          p {
            .sidebar-full-name {
              color: #419e7d;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .sidebar-nav-link:hover {
    .sidebar-full-name {
      color: #419e7d;
    }

    .commDashboardImage {
      background: url(../../../engageStudio/assets/images/dashboard-hover.svg)
        no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .engageAIImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/offerHubHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .opportunityImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/merHubHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .campaignHubImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/sugMerHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .resultsMapImage {
      background: url(../../assets/images/offersMapHover.svg) no-repeat center;
      width: 60px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
  }

  .commDashboardImage {
    background: url(../../../engageStudio/assets/images/dashboard-icon.svg)
      no-repeat center;
    width: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .engageAIImage {
    background: url(../../assets/images/offerHub.svg) no-repeat center;
    width: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .opportunityImage {
    background: url(../../assets/images/merHub.svg) no-repeat center;
    width: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .campaignHubImage {
    background: url(../../assets/images/sugMer.svg) no-repeat center;
    width: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .resultsMapImage {
    background: url(../../assets/images/offersMap.svg) no-repeat center;
    width: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .h-30 {
    height: 30px !important;
  }
}
.nav-item.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: Is it your images that flicker ? You might want to check how to preload them if it's the case.

Comment: I guess it's images only flickering. But initial and hovered images are different. Can you suggest any fix in above code that might resolve the issue?

Comment: You could load both images before the hover: `.foo { background-image: url('img.jpg'), url('img-hover.jpg'); }` and on hover `.foo { background-image: url('img-hover.jpg'); }`

Comment: Great.Thank you. Flicker gone. But as we're preloading both images, there's has been slight change in tone. Suppose previously original image had weight 0.4, now it's 0.5-0.6. Can you suggest how to keep it intact? Otherwise everything seems fine

Comment: Well, you could define the size of the background, to make it `0` or you could preload the image in an empty pseudo element. But without working on the real files, it's hard to tell you.